# Using a server for a turn game (Android) - how to store data?

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets

I am writing a simple turn game in Android for two players. I already developed an offline version (when two persons exchange the phone) and now want to create an on-line one.

They way I wanted to do it was to use Tomcat or my own PHP server for my website. My question would be whether it is possible and how to store data?

I think that the only thing I need to send to the server is the current score and an array representing the board. Then I'll be able to retrieve these pieces of information on client's side. Am I thinking properly?

I gotta say, I am completely new to all this stuff. I talked to my friend who programs in Java and he told me that I should use Tomcat. But how? It is a local server so the only way it could work would be when two mobile phones are connected to the same network or what?

Comment: Tomcat is no more a "local sever" than a PHP server is; either can be hosted anywhere that supports them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to implement a set of [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST#RESTful_web_services) services on an online server.
You can use Tomcat if you want, but the cheapest approach would be to have a simple web hosting with i.e. PHP.
Create REST API's like `/get/board, /get/move, /update/move, /authenticated` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to start out is probably not even with any real service, but just a couple of PHP scripts and an MySQL database.

You'll need some server, per example just a simple FTP server where you can put some on-the-internet reachable scripts on, and host the (MySQL) database.

Then per example for keeping the score you'll just need 2 scripts : 1 that saves and 1 that retrieves the score of a player.

Saving the score will just demand you to call on a link as per example: 
www.server.com/saveScore.php?playerId=111&score=60 
In the PHP you could just take this out with $_GET['playerId'] and $_GET['score'] and save those values in to your database with a query.

Returning the score to your app could work out with calling a link as:
www.server.com/retrieveScore.php?playerId=111 
Which will simply query your database for the info on that player, and then print it as XML or JSON. 
Then your app can just parse the response (xml/json) again.

A good idea would be to move this from $_GET to $_POST (POST is not visible in the link, but you'll need a bit more complicated code to transmit the data through that) once it works.

Once you've got that going you can work on actually building a service, REST would be a good choice, in order to increase maintainability, extendability and security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The thing is, this is my term project from programming and it should involve as much Java as possible and very little of other stuff. I want to narrow down the amount of PHP and SQL to minimum! I don't think there is a need of a database, the game lasts a few minutes and there is no need to store data in a database, just an array should do. Or not?

Comment: Well, even without using PHP you can still do around the same with Java, but you'll need a server that supports Java, which generally is just a harder set-up.
About the database, its hardly ever a real 'need' but if you're going to the cleanest way i'd go for it anyway and its really not that much work, maybe even easier.
If its of no importance to maintain data for a longer period of time and is just to show a proof of concept you could also take a look at things like bluetooth and NFC instead to communicate between 2 devices.